# td id is not getting in HTML Table pagination

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have HTML table with multiple records which i used pagination concept. The first `td` of every `tr` is **checkbox with unique id**. When am clicking on button, i need to get **all the checkbox id's which are checked**.

Below is the code which I am using. I am getting checkbox id's which are in first page but in remaining pages checkbox's checked ids are not coming.

```
 $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td"), function (index, item) {
        var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
        var $rowid = $row.attr('id');


        //var usedvalue = $row.find('td:eq(12) input').val(); // position of textbox for used is 12
       var combo = $rowid;

        selectedDetails.push(combo);

    }).toArray();


    selectedIdsStr = selectedDetails.join();
```

Td element in my table

```
   <td style="width:3px;"><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" id="@item.ContainerID"></td>
```

I tried mutliple approaches i.e looping the tbody instead of class of a td. But i couldnt find any solution.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Well are the elements actually on the page when not shown?

Answer (score 0):

try finding all the td which are checkbox. and then filter checked checkboxes from those.

```
$.each($("td input:checkbox"), function(index, item){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        selectedDetails.push($(this).attr("id"));
    }
}).toArray();

selectedIdsStr = selectedDetails.join();
```

I am sure this will solve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. the problem is suppose i have checked 2 chekboxes in different pages, i click on submit button when am in second page. it's geeting second page checked id but not first page id.

Comment: Then you will need to store the checked id's on page change, by page number.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the input:checked jquery selector to get an array of the checkboxes then loop over those to display the id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#getButton").on("click", function() {
    displayCheckedIds();
   });
});

function displayCheckedIds() {
    var checkedBoxes = $("input:checked"); // Gets an array of checked boxes
  $("#displayIds").html("");  //clear out existing
  $.each(checkedBoxes, function(){
    $("#displayIds").append($(this).attr("id") + "<br>");
  });
}
```

[Js Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2xdr0u/)